# Alter tables on multiple databases from same server

Tags: mysql

I have multiple databases all having the same table structure on one server.
I need to change three tables in all databases which name is

xx_databasename

where xx is an isoAlpha2Code of the country the database os connected to.

So how can I perform a query like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename;
CREATE TABLE tablename (....);
```

on each database with just one mySQL command?

Comment: Is that multiple databases all within ONE INSTANCE of MySQL?

Comment: Yes all on one instance and server

Comment: check this solution out: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622691/delete-table-across-multiple-databases). I think it will solve the problem

Comment: You cannot do all three databases in one command, but you can do `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DB1.tablename;` and then `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DB2.tablename;` etc etc This assumes that the user account you are logged in with will work and allow whatever command you try and execute on all 3 databases